# Using javascript to open a url with parameter in current windows fails on IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript

In trying to lunch a URL with the session variable in current window, it works fine for Firefox but strips off the parameters in Chrome and IE, but works as expected in Firefox.

So, I have the form input field like so:

```
<input class="ppb-search" placeholder="Search Blog" type="text" id="searchTextDesktop" onKeyPress="SearchText(event, this)">
```

And the JavaScript to open the URL having the parameter in current window is like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SearchText(e, input) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode                                
                var textSearch = document.getElementById("searchTextDesktop").value;
                var url = '$searchPage?search='+textSearch;
                //alert("Test open search URL: "+url); 
                window.location.href=url;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I’ve also tried `window.open(url, "_self ");`

Comment: My guess is you are not preventing the form submission and you should be using encodeURIComponent

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cy5fvmn0/ This is work what is problem?

Comment: @Murad Sofiyev - The problem is that for IE and Chrome, the `?search='+textSearch` is stripped off. Therefore the parameter is not parsed in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MuradSofiyev - You are correct. I was parsing the expected path from vtl to javascript instead of setting the path in the javascript variable. Therefore the $searchPage variable was returning null.

The solution ended up being setting the URL path in the javascript instead of using the $searchPage vtl variable set in the back-end vtl script.

So the script becomes:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
var searchPage = "/searchResults/index.dot";    
function SearchText(e, input) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode                                
                var textSearch = document.getElementById("searchTextDesktop").value;
                var url = searchPage+'?search='+textSearch;
                //alert("Test open search URL: "+url); 
                window.location.href=url;
        }
    }
</script>`
```